# SSIS error - parameters not set correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a fairly simple T-SQL query and I want it to be executed on an `Execute SQL` task.

Query is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblCustomers (Id, Name, Address)
SELECT M.Id,
       M.Name,
       M.Address
FROM dbo.tblMain AS M
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Id
   FROM dbo.Child AS A
   WHERE (StartDate <=
            (SELECT GETDATE() - ? AS Col1))  ...notice the ? which acts as the parameter
     OR (EndDate <=
           (SELECT GETDATE() - ? AS Col1)) .....same value needs to be set here

     ) AS b ON M.Id = A.Id
```

`?` is properly set in the task. It is a simple int variable. And if i replace the `?` with a constant value, it works.

Comment: SSIS will interpret two ?s as two separate variables.  Did you map the parameter twice?

Comment: even if i keep only one...it doesn't work

Comment: What happens when it "doesn't work"?   Do you get an error?

Comment: It's best to [avoid the shorthand for datetime arithmetic](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause for this issue is not setting the parameter name correctly.
In the 'Execute SQL Task', go to the 'Parameter Mapping' Tab and make sure that the parameter name is set as the order of the parameter execution.
so the first parameter's name will be 0, the second is 1 etc.